# Calculating flowpaths downstream of a point

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, hydrology

I am assessing the flood risk posed by pipeline failure.  I need to calculate the likely flow-paths for flood water downstream of critical locations along the pipeline using GIS.

I'm familiar with ArcGIS and QGIS/GRASS/SAGA methods for calculating channel networks and catchments **upstream** from a point but what would be the best method for assessing **downstream** flow-paths originating at a point location?

Ideally any method would be fairly automated as a number of locations are being assessed.

I have ArcGIS 9.3 and QGIS (latest version) available to me.

Comment: maybe this will help:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14622/given-a-terrain-how-to-draw-the-stream-flow-path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a tool in the free and open-source (GNU GPL licensed) GIS [Whitebox Geospatial Analysis Tools](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/download.shtml) that can identify the flowpath from any point or collection of points specified either as a ShapeFile or as a categorical raster. The tool is called **Trace Downslope Flowpaths**:

[image]

[image]

The tool takes a D8 flow pointer (flow directions) grid as an input, which can be calculated using the **[D8 Flow Pointer](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/Help/FlowPointerD8.html)** tool, also found in the **Hydrological Tools** toolbox. If the steepest descent (D8) flow algorithm is not appropriate for your application, let me know and I'll modify the tool to optionally output the dispersive D-infinity flowpath as well. The second input is the 'Seed Point' file, which can either be a raster (with all valid, greater than zero valued pixels serving as flowpath starting points) or a ShapeFile of points, which can be derived through on-screen digitizing if desired. Please note that I am the lead developer of the Whitebox Geospatial Analysis Tools project.

Comment: That is exactly the tool I was looking for.  I'm familiar with Whitebox as I was taught TAS under John Lindsay at Manchester (I don't know if that's you?).

Comment: @EdRollason Hi Ed, yep, that's me. Manchester seems so long ago now!

Answer (score 1):

If you're already familiar with the upstream trace tools, you should be able to apply the following steps:

1. Create a constant raster. A constant value of zero is a convenient number.
2. Subtract the elevation raster from the constant raster, leaving you with an inverse of the elevation raster. If you used a constant value of zero, your inverse raster is now a negative of your elevation raster (ex: elevation 679.00 = -679.00).
3. Apply the trace upstream tools to your inverse raster to obtain the downstream flow path.

I haven't done this myself, but it would be my first approach. If you, or anyone else tries this, please share any challenges you run into.

Comment: I am currently trying a version of this method and it is only getting me so far... please view http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214687/distance-to-nearest-flow-channel