# Calculating flow distance of pixel from outlet using R?

Tags: raster, r, dem, flow-accumulation

I have created these raster files for a river basin:

- DEM
- Flow Direction
- Flow Accumulation

Also, I have another raster with values of rainfall.

All the 4 rasters have same spatial extent, resolution and dimensions.

How can I calculate the flow distance of each pixel of rainfall from the outlet of the basin?

Theoretically, I have to follow the Flow Accumulation values, but I'm not sure how to implement it and whether there are existing implementations.

I am currently working with raster package in R, but I am open to other platforms.

Comment: Flow length is one of hydrology tools

Comment: Not sure how to use it in programming. Also, I need to calcualte the length from every pixel.

Comment: Use it the same way you are using DEM and others. Flow Length gives you length at every point, at the end of the day raster IS collection of regularly placed points

Comment: Thank you. Is there an example code I can look at? I used ArcGIS GUI for creating the rasters. But the rest of it needs to happen in code...

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136715/how-to-get-cell-value-along-flow-direction/136954#136954