# Measure Flowpath Direction and Length from a Point

Tags: qgis, flow, path

Using QGIS 3.28.2-Firenze. I created a depressionless DEM, created a shapefile with points I want to measure flow from by using "Add Point Feature", ran D8 Flow Pointer, and then ran TraceDownslopeFlowpath, but I did not get any flow paths shown.

What step am I missing to show the flowpaths?

Similar Question:  [Calculating flowpaths downstream of a point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114947/calculating-flowpaths-downstream-of-a-point/449212?noredirect=1#comment733716_449212)

Comment: Here is a snapshot of the output.  No flow path lines were drawn when I went to the layer and tried to classify the values.  Flowpoints are numbered 1-7.  I must be missing a step. 
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/1dapc2gks0w9hxr/Capture.JPG?dl=0

Comment: As I dig into this, I think it has something to do with assigning a z value to the shapefile with points.  When I use the "Identify Features" tool, there is only an X and Y value to the point.  I've tried to use the v.drape and v.to.3d tools but I can't get them to assign a Z value.  I'm still digging into this.

Comment: OK, I assigned Z values by using the "Drape (set Z value from raster)" and ran the "TraceDownslopeFlowpath" tool and it worked!  But I don't understand what the different colors signify since the color changes from red to blue on the same main stream.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/kivldacz7tqugf1/Diff%20colors.JPG?dl=0